# How to add listener to android Navigation Architecture Component action animation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components

I want to execute some code by the end of an animation that I've set to an action, is there some way to add a listener to navigation controller action animation?

Comment: You can refer to the second answer on this topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59147647/prevent-views-from-being-clicked-until-animation-added-to-action-via-navigation/64106156#64106156